# Resend the request to the same queue in RabbitMQ and Ruby

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a ruby process to consume RabbitMQ queue :

```
AMQP.start(:host => $AMQP_URL) do |connection|
  @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
  @queue   ||= @channel.queue("results")

  @queue.subscribe do |body|
    puts "Received -> #{body}"       
    # Publish the same message again to the same queue 
  end
end
```

I know it is not practical, but I would love to know how am I supposed to publish the same message to the same queue, it didn't work out for me with direct channel, if there is anyways even just to keep the msg in the queue instead of deleting it or just to republish the msg again it would be great

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it would just be to reject the message with a negative acknowledgement, it will be automatically requeued:

```
@queue.subscribe do |metadata, payload|
  # reject and requeue
  channel.reject(metadata.delivery_tag, true)
end
```

Anyway, if you want to do the publish manually, the "metadata" parameter in the previous example will give you all the information you need.

Comment: I really appreciate ur welling to help here, but this way, I'm supposed to have a loot of printing out the payload, but it didn't work for me this way, i just want the system in certain condition to keep the msg in the queue and keep accessing it

Comment: The answer given by @Loris is correct, if you want to keep the message in the queue then you will need to reject it.
However, I would say that you probably need to rethink your design as this is pretty messy.

Comment: Intuitively I would think rejecting the message on a direct queue, as opposed to just doing a basic ack and compiling fail stats in the app logs, would be used to register the fail so you can see the event(s) in the management console.

Looking over the various sections in the console, I see place holders for messages that are either unconfirmed or unacknowledged, but not seeing anything that would indicate message rejections.

If rejects, as a stat, aren't collected administratively, and if you don't need to re-queue, ack seems to serve the same functionality as reject(false).